# Numpy matrix concat in stepwise procedure

Tags: python, numpy

My intention is to build a stepwise subset seletor for regression based on the aggregate group of features in numpy arrays a, b, and c.  I know how to do this looking at all of the columns (posted below), what I don't know how to make work is handling groups of columns.   Here is a representation of my data:

```
a = np.array([[ 1.,  1.],
              [ 1.,  1.],
              [ 1.,  1.]])

b = np.array([[  88.,    42.5,    9. ],
              [ 121.5,   76.,    42.5],
              [ 167.,  121.5,   88. ]])

c = np.array([[  88.,    42.5,   13. ],
              [ 117.5,   72.,    42.5],
              [ 163.,   117.5,  88. ]])

total features = [a,b,c]
result = np.empty((3,8), dtype=object)

n, p = result.shape
result = np.c_[a,b,c]
```

Which produces the expected result:

```
[[  1.    1.    88.   42.5   9.   88.   42.5  13. ]
 [  1.    1.    121.5  76.   42.5 117.5  72.   42.5]
 [  1.    1.    167.  121.5  88.  163.  117.5  88. ]]
```

Going back to the stepwise procedure, here is how I handle column selection looking at each feature individually, then append the best model to features_in_model after performing a fit on all available features in the model:

```
features_in_model = [] 
excluded = list(set(x_train.columns)-set(features_in_model))
for feature in excluded:
     x_train_new = x_train[features_in_model+[feature]]
.....
```

How can I build the list "excluded" (variable above) when handling groups of features for comparison.
The excluded list should start full with all features included and at each iteration one group gets removed.

For reference, here is a forward stepwise procedure:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24405/how-to-do-stepwise-regression-using-sklearn

Comment: Excluded list? How do you mean?

Comment: This is a forward stepwise procedure, so I start with an empty list in features_in_model and then excluded has all of the features.  At each iteration, the best model's feature is added to features_in_model and removed from excluded.  (I have this component working already)

Comment: Ok you forgot to mention you are working on a regression. I kind of understand, but still, it is not very clear.

Comment: Understood, I'll add that to my OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend something like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

feature_set = np.array([[  1.,    1.,    88.,   42.5,   9.,   88.,   42.5,  13. ],
                        [  1.,    1.,    121.5,  76.,  42.5, 117.5, 72.,   42.5],
                        [  1.,    1.,    167.,  121.5,  88.,  163.,  117.5,  88. ]])

feature_column_index = OrderedDict()
feature_column_index['feature1'] = 0
feature_column_index['feature2'] = 1
feature_column_index['feature3'] = 2
feature_column_index['feature4'] = 3
feature_column_index['feature5'] = 4
feature_column_index['feature6'] = 5
feature_column_index['feature7'] = 6
feature_column_index['feature8'] = 7

excluded_features = ['feature2', 'feature7']

include_columns = [kv[1] for kv in feature_column_index.items() if kv[0] not in excluded_features]
print(include_columns)

feature_subset = feature_set[:, include_columns]

print(feature_subset)
```

Which yields the desired subset of columns:

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]

[[  1.   88.   42.5   9.   88.   13. ]
 [  1.  121.5  76.   42.5 117.5  42.5]
 [  1.  167.  121.5  88.  163.   88. ]]
```

Note that the OrderedDict is sorted in insert order.  You can create the feature map in any order you want, but unless you sort it in column index order you'll end up shuffling the order of the columns in the feature subset.  I created it in index order so that it maintains column order in the output.

Since the poster would like to handle these as groups of features ('a', 'b', 'c'), this can be done by maintaining a column mapping according to these subsets of features as a modification of the more general feature mapping above:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

feature_set = np.array([[  1.,    1.,    88.,   42.5,   9.,   88.,   42.5,  13. ],
                        [  1.,    1.,    121.5,  76.,  42.5, 117.5, 72.,   42.5],
                        [  1.,    1.,    167.,  121.5,  88.,  163.,  117.5,  88. ]])

feature_subset_mapping = OrderedDict()
feature_subset_mapping['a'] = [0,1]
feature_subset_mapping['b'] = [2,3,4]
feature_subset_mapping['c'] = [5,6,7]

excluded_subsets = ['b']

include_columns = []
for subset in [kv[1] for kv in feature_subset_mapping.items() if kv[0] not in excluded_subsets]:
    include_columns = include_columns+subset

print(include_columns)

feature_subset = feature_set[:, include_columns]

print(feature_subset)
```

Which yields:

```
[0, 1, 5, 6, 7]

[[  1.    1.   88.   42.5  13. ]
 [  1.    1.  117.5  72.   42.5]
 [  1.    1.  163.  117.5  88. ]]
```

Comment: It's close but say I only have the 3 categories, a, b, and c.  (In reality these are VERY large matrices of the same # of rows but different column lengths.)  I would want to add a with b, and c to start and then peel them off as they get added to the features included index.

Comment: This solution will let you exclude any subset of columns - are you saying you want to exclude only on the basis of groups of columns for each of a, b, c?

Comment: Yes, because a,b and c are slices of the larger feature_set.  Or have your solution work accepting multiple 2D slices of the larger matrix in exluded_columns.  For instance, matrix a is 1280 columns wide by itself, I wouldn't want to handle each one separately.

Comment: This doesn't address my last comment.  If I adapt the lines closer to what I'm trying to do: `feature_subset_mapping['a'] = np.arange(0,2)`
`feature_subset_mapping['b'] = np.arange(2,5)` `feature_subset_mapping['c'] = np.arange(5,8)`  Then I get following error "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (2,) "

Comment: That's because you can't do concatenation with np.arange.  Use list(np.arange()) and it will work just fine.  Or you could change the code in the for loop to concatenate the arrays that come out of np.arange and that will also work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170923/discussion-between-shawn-and-t3am5hark).

Comment: As I work on this I don't think this will work but I'm having a hard time explaining the problem. It has to do with include_columns being variable based on a score on each iteration.  I'll make a new question after I think about it some more.